# How do I change the default Type for Numeric deserialization?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm deserializing some properties to a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

When I deserialize some json, it populates the `Dictionary` with `Int64` objects rather than `Int32`. I would like it to choose `Int32` as the default well knowing that I could have javascript Numerics that would overflow on conversion. Throwing an exception in that case would be entirely acceptable.

Is there any way to achieve that? I'm hoping for some nice attributes or a convenient interface that could be implemented and added to the `JsonSerializer`. And I fear that I have to go deep down into the depths of Json.NET.

Basically I would like to have some way to control the known types for the objects so that I could get `Int32`'s instead of `Int64` and `DateTimes` instead of `Strings`.

Comment: Comments tidied: OP is aware of the POCO option but doesn't want to do that

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do that.

There was an [issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606030722/http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20832) on this subject, but it has been closed.
Some comments from the author on the issue:

> Json.NET by default reads integer values as Int64 because there is no way to know whether the value should be Int32 or Int64, and Int64 is less likely to overflow. For a typed property the deserializer knows to convert the Int64 to a Int32 but because your property is untyped you are getting an Int64. [...] It is just the way Json.NET has to work.

The easiest solution would of coure be to change the type to `Dictionary<string, int>`, but I suppose you are not only reading numerics and thus are stuck with `object`.

Another option would be to either use [Serialization Callbacks](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationCallbacks.html) and manually convert those `Int64`s to `Int32` or create your own <del>[Contract Resolver](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)</del> [JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) and directly control the (de-)serialization.

---

**Edit:**  I created a little example to be more specific.

Here is a very basic converter that only works with your specifc Dictionary:

```
public class Int32Converter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        // may want to be less concrete here
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite {
        // we only want to read (de-serialize)
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // again, very concrete
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        reader.Read();

        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
            string propertyName = reader.Value as string;
            reader.Read();

            object value;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
                value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);      // convert to Int32 instead of Int64
            else
                value = serializer.Deserialize(reader);     // let the serializer handle all other cases
            result.Add(propertyName, value);
            reader.Read();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // since CanWrite returns false, we don't need to implement this
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can either use attributes to decorate members with your converter or [pass it as parameter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) to a (de-)serialize method. Here's an example where I used an attribute:

```
    [JsonObject]
public class MyObject {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Int32Converter))]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code I used to test the implementation:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyObject test = new MyObject();
        test.Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "int", 15 }, { "string", "hi" }, { "number", 7 } };
        Print("Original:", test);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        Console.WriteLine("JSON:\n{0}\n", json);

        MyObject parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
        Print("Deserialized:", parsed);
    }

    private static void Print(string heading, MyObject obj) {
        Console.WriteLine(heading);
        foreach (var kvp in obj.Properties)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} of {2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, kvp.Value.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Without the converter, the result would be:

```
Deserialized:
int = 15 of Int64
string = hi of String
number = 7 of Int64
```

and with the converter it is:

```
Deserialized:
int = 15 of Int32
string = hi of String
number = 7 of Int32
```

Comment: What a totally awesome answer. The Int32Converter class is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not going to use it since I've changed how I do these things, but at the time this would have been the perfect answer. :)

Comment: This is working fine when you have integer values in the dictionary. However, if you have integer values in the objects in the dictionary than it doesn't work. Any suggestions for this please?

Works if Dictionary has  { {"First" , 1}, {"Second", 2} }

Doesn't work if Dictionary has { {"First", {Age: "1"}}, {"Second", {Age: "2"}}

Comment: @HamidShahid depends on how you de-serialize. If you own the object in the Dictionary (the one with the `Age` field), you can write a converter for it instead of for the dictionary. However if you're dealing with various different objects I wouldn't recommend it. You could create a generic numeric converter like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745866/how-can-i-restore-the-int-deserialization-behavior-after-upgrading-json-net). Keep in mind that my answer is pretty old by now and there may be a built-in solution by now.

Comment: @HamidShahid I haven't found anything builtin yet, but inspired by this answer I [wrote a more generalized converter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748973/1037948) on a similar question that may take care of your problem -- the important part is checking if type is `Object` so the converter will apply.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
   var variable = Convert.ToInt32(object)
```

Iterate the `Dictionary<string,object>` once and rewrite its `object` with this `Int32`, or do the `Int32` conversion each time you read the `object`.

Comment: Json.NET deserialize numbers as boxed long (Int64). You can also unbox it and convert it to int: `var variable = (int)(long)object;`
But I think your solution is safer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is working well for me:

```
public class ParseNumbersAsInt32Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(long) || objectType == typeof(long?) || objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value != null && reader.Value is long)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
        }
        return reader.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was much easier to get in touch with overriding JsonConvert and to add more functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm accepting Enzi's answer since it's what I was asking for.

However, since then I've changed my strategy.

Right now I'm deserializing to a `ChangeSet<T>` which instead of the dictionary has a strongly typed `Entity` (T) object with the changes. It also has a `List<string>` with the property names of the properties that was present in the incoming json. I then populate that list during deserialization using a custom MediaFormatter. That way I get a strongly typed object and correct deserialization of all properties, and I know from the list what properties I should set on my collection of T when I want to do my batch operation.

This way I basically use my entities as DTO's without having to have a myriad of different DTO's for different batch operations. Is pretty sleek if I do say so myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this question, because I hit the same problem. I decided to just go back and convert them.

```
var items = GetDataFile<Item[]>("Items");
foreach(var m in items)
{
    // Deserialized int becomes long if object type. I want int.
    foreach(var pk in m.Properties.Keys)
    {
        if(m.Properties[pk] is long)
        {
            m.Properties[pk] = Convert.ToInt32(m.Properties[pk]);
        }
    }
}
```