# Can I Deserialize a JSON string that contains 0.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

The JSON I'm getting back from a webservice has an integer incorrectly represented as 0.0. My deserialization code looks like this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var ret = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
```

And I get an error like this:

> Input string '0.0' is not a valid integer.

My question is, is there a way to specify a less strict deserialization method so that I can parse this string?

EDIT: The web service returns no schema so I don't know why the deserializer tries to convert it to an int instead of a float or double.

Comment: it is not int. Must change to Decimal/Double ? Or use diff Json deserializer, or write custom Int deserializer. They might claim it is int (meaning no digits after dot/comma) but their API sends it as a double/float/decimal.

Comment: Good point, but there's no schema returned from the webservice so I don't know why it's expecting an int.

Comment: your T model/class has property int, instead of double?

Comment: Here's an example custom JsonConverter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745866/how-can-i-restore-the-int-deserialization-behavior-after-upgrading-json-net

Comment: Ah yes I autogenerated these classes and it set it to int. Stupid mistake, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of, say, `"0.1"` instead of `"0.0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you should go ahead and creat your classes on [Json -> C#](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
var o = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(myjsondata);
```

You can use the C# dynamic type to make things easier. This technique also makes re-factoring simpler as it does not rely on magic-strings. Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>()`to deserialize this string into a dynamic type then simply access its properties in the usual way in C#.

Im not sure why youre getting

> Input string '0.0' is not a valid integer.

since if you dont have any Json data it should just be left at null and you shouldnt have this problem