# Make Newtonsoft JsonConvert Default to Int32 Rather Than Int64

Tags: c#

I am converting Json to ExpandoObject by doing this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText)
```

The integer I got was Int64 but I prefer Int32.

Is there any settings in JsonConvert that I can use to change the default behavior?

Comment: It is just the usual .Net System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject. I assume it is explicitly convertible to IDictionary<string, object>

Comment: Did the value fit in an Int32? I don't think Newtonsoft would favor longs over ints.

Comment: Yes. The value is small and it fits into Int32

Comment: Could you provide the JSON representation of your object?

Comment: It can be as simple as this {"name":"John", "age":22} . Then the 22 turns out to be an Int64

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting a post by [James Newton King](http://james.newtonking.com/bio) (maker of Newtonsoft.JSON) in [this](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20832) thread:

> Json.NET by default reads integer values as Int64 because there is no way to know whether the value should be Int32 or Int64, and Int64 is less likely to overflow. For a typed property the deserializer knows to convert the Int64 to a Int32 but because your property is untyped you are getting an Int64.

This sort of question has been asked on SO before. Basically it comes down to: you need to create a custom converter. If not for your object, then for integers.

For reference regarding that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748973/7662085) answer by user [drzaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037948/drzaus) who tackled exactly this issue, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444519/7662085) one by [enzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345004/enzi), who goes into more detail.