# Powershell Core deserializes numbers in JSON as Int64 vs Windows Powershell which does it as Int32

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

Please observe:

**Windows Powershell**

```
C:\> ("1" | ConvertFrom-Json).gettype().name
Int32
C:\>
```

**Powershell Core**

```
C:\> ("1" | ConvertFrom-Json).gettype().name
Int64
C:\>
```

This is not benign. Consider a map with keys being integers:

```
$x = @{
    123 = 1
}
```

The key 123 is an `Int32`, not `Int64`. So, if 123 comes from parsed JSON it would be of different types in different shells. Now:

```
C:\> $x[[Int32]123]
1
C:\> $x[[Int64]123]
C:\>
```

And this is true on both shells. This change in behavior wrecks havoc in our automation scripts that manipulate things using REST APIs.

Can this behavior of Powershell Core be turned off?

Comment: Why don't you cast the key into the type needed?

Comment: @Zan Lynx, for one key this is easy, for hundreds... (samples and real life are not always the same ;) ). @iRon, try this on PowerShell 7 `$x=@{One=1}`, then `$x.One.GetType()` and then `($x|ConvertTo-Json|ConvertFrom-Json).One.GetType()`. This is indeed an actual problem, I don't think there is a way to turn this off. May be a suggestion for a commit on the next release with a `-Legacy` or `-Int32` parameter for `ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: The behavior of ConvertFrom-Json changed in PowerShell [Core] v6+ is slightly changed, I think this is related to describtion in this issue: [***#9207* convertto-json bigint is not properly serialized**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9207)

Comment: Why are we talking about `ConvertTo-Json` at all?

Comment: What is the connection between these two phenomena? Are you parsing json leaf values and using them as dynamic dictionary keys without converting them to strings first?

Comment: I am processing REST Api results in any way suitable, which may include using values returned from the REST Api to lookup entries in a hashtable. And these values can be numbers and no I do not cast them to strings because I never had to.

Comment: You do have a point: `$a = "1" | ConvertFrom-Json; (@{ $a = 2 }).1`, returns in `2` in Windows PowerShell 5, and nothing in PowerShell Core 7.1.

Comment: See also: [Make Newtonsoft JsonConvert Default to Int32 Rather Than Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010307/1701026)

Comment: FYI: I have reported this issue here: [Powershell Core deserializes numbers in JSON as Int64 vs Windows Powershell which does it as Int32 #14264](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14264)

Comment: @iRon - thank you for the github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **The two PowerShell editions use *different implementations***, causing the divergent behavior you observed:

  - *Windows PowerShell* uses a custom implementation, whereas ***PowerShell [Core] v6+*, as of v7.1, uses the [Json.NET library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)** behind the scenes; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010307/45375) for that library's rationale for deserializing to `System.Int64` (`[long]`) by default.
- [***Update*: It is unclear if this will happen** - a move to `System.Text.Json` would take away the ability to use *single*-quoted property names and string values, which both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) currently support.]
  As of PowerShell 7.1, there's a **planned[?] move to the now native .NET JSON functionality** (available in .NET Core 3+) available via the [`System.Text.Json` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0), which ***may* restore serializing to `System.Int32` (`[int]`) by default**, given that breaking changes are inevitable anyway:

  - See the discussion in [GitHub issue #14264](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14264) (created by [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) based on this question) and [GitHub PR #11198](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11198) [*now closed*], which is preparing the move to `System.Text.Json`.
- A related problem is that **numbers too large to fit into a `System.Int64` (`[long]`) are also serialized differently** (see [GitHub issue #9207](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/#9207)):

  - Windows PowerShell: first chooses `System.Decimal` (`[decimal]`) and for even larger numbers `System.Double` (`[double]`).
  - PowerShell [Core] as of v7.1: always chooses `System.BigInt` (`[bigint]`).
- Also, there are **differences with respect to the number *formats*** supported:

  - Windows PowerShell does *not* recognize *hexadecimal* numbers (e.g., `0x10`), in accordance with the [JSON spec](https://json.org)<sup>[1]</sup>, whereas PowerShell [Core] as of v7.1 *does*; however, as another extension to the spec, both support *scientific notation* (e.g., `1e2` for `100`) and parse it as `[double]`.
  - Windows PowerShell, as another extension to the spec, *does* support `+`-prefixed numbers (e.g., `+10`), whereas PowerShell [Core] as of v7.1 does *not*.
  - (Also, both editions support *single*-quoted strings as an extension.)

---

**Workaround**:

- Generally, note that the problem may often not surface, given PowerShell's ability to mix different numeric types and widen types on demand.
- However, as the question shows, when numbers are used as the *keys of a hashtable (dictionary)*, a type-exact value *must* be passed for lookup in order to locate entries.

Therefore, the simplest workaround is to **cast the *hashtable key* to `[int]`**, which allows later lookups with just, say, `[123]` (or even `.123`):

```
# Works in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core]
# Without the [int] cast, the lookup would fail in PowerShell [Core] as of v7.1
PS> $key = '123' | ConvertFrom-Json; @{ [int] $key = 'bingo' }[123]
bingo
```

**Another option is to use a `[pscustomobject]`** rather than a hashtable, in which case the numeric *keys* implicitly become property *names*, which are always *strings*.

```
# Note the use of .123, i.e. property access.
PS> $key = '123' | ConvertFrom-Json; ([pscustomobject] @{ [int] $key = 'bingo' }).123
bingo
```

This would work even with a *numeric* variable:

```
$lookup=123; ([pscustomobject] @{ [int] $key = 'bingo' }).$lookup
```

*Caveat*: When a key is implicitly stringified to become a property name, it is invariably a *decimal* representation that is used; e.g., `[pscustomobject] @{ [int] 0x10 = 'bingo' }` results in an object whose property name is `'16'`.<sup>[2]</sup>

However, note that hashtables / dictionaries are more lightweight than `[pscustomobject]`s.

---

<sup>[1] However, the [JSON5](https://json5.org/) format, which is meant to improve on JSON, does support hex. numbers, along with other notable improvements, such as support for comments, extraneous trailing commas, and *single*-quoted strings.</sup>

<sup>[2] Also, with `[double]` values the conversion is *culture-sensitive*, so that `1.2` can in some cultures result in `'1.2'` (as of v7.1, which is unexpected - see [GitHub issue #14278](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14278)); also, large `[double]`s can end up in *scientific* notation, so that `1000000000000000.1` results in `'1E+15'`. That said, using `[double]`s as dictionary keys is generally ill-advised, given the accuracy limits of its from-decimal-number conversion.</sup>

Comment: Also noted in https://github.com/json-schema-org/understanding-json-schema/issues/138#issuecomment-734352615