# How to pass a JSON text as a parameter to powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, command-line

What I want to do is pretty simple. I have a PowerShell script that should accept JSON text as a parameter. It looks like it is not simple at all!

I checked these pages in my attempt to learn how it should be done. [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1), [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing?view=powershell-5.1) and [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1). I found no clear explanations. What I see is, actually, contradicts these documents. Command-line rules are not the same as general ones.

I'm on PowerShell 5.1

I use this script for testing:

test.ps1

```
param($json)
Write-Host $json
```

I try to pass this JSON text.

```
{"name" : "value"}
```

What I see.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "{"name" : "value"}"
name : value
```

No braces. Double quotation marks were completely removed.
Let's try to escape them.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "{`"name`" : `"value`"}"
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
```

The backtick symbol doesn't help. Let's try to double quotation marks. Doubling is a very popular trick in command-line magic.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "{""name"" : ""value""}"
The string is missing the terminator: ".
```

Let's try to triple marks, because why not.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "{"""name""" : """value"""}"
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
```

OK, let's try single quotes.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 '{"name" : "value"}'
{name : value}
```

We've got braces, but not double quotation marks. Let's try to escape them once again.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 '{`"name`" : `"value`"}'
{`name` : `value`}
```

Something eats our double quotation marks before PS has a chance to escape them.

Doubling?

```
powershell .\test.ps1 '{""name"" : ""value""}'
{name : value}
```

Tripling?

```
powershell .\test.ps1 '{"""name""" : """value"""}'
{"name" : "value"}
```

It works! How ugly it is!

I wonder if somebody has a good explanation of what's going on. I'd appreciate any link on documentation/article that can explain how it actually works. Tripling quotes doesn't looks too bad for me, but my JSON parameter has several levels of nesting, it looks like I can end up with things like 7 quotes before an element.

-EncodedCommand in powershel.exe gives me a sad feeling that there is no easy solution.

**Update**. As @mklement0 pointed out, it is a CMD shell that processes this command line first. CMD uses double quotes to handle parameters that have a space in them. Later, Powershell removes pairs of double quotes. Powershell recognizes \ as an escape character. That means that

1. The very first and the very last quote will be removed in any case
2. We can use \ to escape all internal quotes

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "{\"name\" : \"value\"}"
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
```

in this case, this string reached the powershell.exe, `{"name" : "value"}`. PowerShell has tried to parse it, and this syntax is not valid. To make it a string, we need another pair of quotes around, and here powershell's single quotes are very helpful.

```
powershell .\test.ps1 "'{\"name\" : \"value\"}'"
{"name" : "value"}
```

The better solution is to use -File, as @mklement0 suggested. In this case a parameter won't be interpreted as a PS code.

```
powershell -File .\test.ps1 "{\"name\" : \"value\"}"
```

This update has been edited after @mklement0 comment to be factually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *outside* PowerShell, such as from `cmd.exe` / a batch file, use the following:

```bash
powershell -File .\test.ps1 "{\"name\" : \"value\"}"
```

Note:

- **`-File` is the best way to invoke a script file via `powershell.exe`, the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, because it doesn't subject the subsequent arguments to additional interpretation as PowerShell code (which is what happens by default, which implies `-Command`).

  - Note that only `"` chars. have *syntactic* function on the PowerShell command line, and *unescaped* ones are *removed* during command-line parsing.
  - For guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).
- **In its CLI arguments, PowerShell requires `"` chars. that should  be *preserved* as part of an argument / command to be escaped as `\"`** (unlike *inside* a PowerShell session, where it is `` `" ``).

  - Note: `\"` works robustly on the PowerShell side, but there can be **edge cases** where **calling from `cmd.exe` / a batch file** requires an alternative form of escaping, namely **`"^""`** (sic) or, with [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, **`""`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.

---

**Alternative**, with ***non-standard* `'...'` JSON quoting** (single-quoting):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, PowerShell's [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet - both in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) as of 7.3.3 - accepts `'...'` in lieu of `"..."` around property names and string values (escape *embedded* `'` as ''`then), which you can use to avoid the need for escaped`"` chars.:

```bash
:: SEE CAVEAT BELOW
powershell -File .\test.ps1 "{'name' : 'value'}"
```

**Caveat**:

- The JSON standard does *not* allow use of `'...'`, so depending on who consumes the JSON this may *not* work.

  - Notably, the [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) .NET APIs do *not* support `'...'`.
  - There was a [plan](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11198) - seemingly shelved for now - to shift the implementation of `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` to `System.Text.Json`, but, as zett42 points out, this would constitute a major breaking change, making this unlikely to happen.
- Therefore use `'...'`-quoting *only* if you know that you'll be using `ConvertFrom-Json` or another JSON parser known to support `'...'`.
- As an aside:

  - It's best to stay away from *other* non-standard JSON features, such as the ability to tolerate an extraneous trailing `,`, support for `//` comments, and support for *unquoted* property names (but not string values), given that cross-edition support is *not* ensured:

    - *Windows PowerShell*'s implementation of `ConvertFrom-Json` (and `ConvertTo-Json`) differs from that of [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): the former uses a custom implementation, the latter is based on the [Json.NET library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
  - It is only the Json.NET-based PowerShell (Core) implementation that supports these non-standard features (by invariable default)(`System.Text.Json` supports them on an opt-in basis, but does *not* support `'...'`-quoting, as stated, and also not unquoted property names).

    - zett42 points to the [list of JSON features supported by Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm) juxtaposed with *older* .NET JSON APIs; note that the trailing-comma support is *not* mentioned, however.
  - In addition to these *syntax* differences, there are *behavioral* cross-edition differences as well, namely with respect to:

    - The default .NET integer data type chosen (`[int]` (`System.Int32`) vs. `[long]` (`System.Int64`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65040970/45375).
    - How .NET `[datetime]` instances are serialized and deserialized - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532663/45375).

Comment: Oh, it is so obvious when you answered! Of course, CMD processes it first! I'll try your advice and reply later.

Comment: @Alsin, yes, `cmd.exe` processes first, but at least in your example command that doesn't make a difference - the command line is in essence passed through to PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cmdlets of `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` to handle your json objects if they are coming from other sources or as strings. Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7)

Here is an example of how to convert a string json output to a powershell object that can be better manipulated in your script:

```
Command-ThatProducesJsonString | ConvertFrom-Json
```

If you were using this pipe setup to pass the json into your function, you could pipe it in after:

```
Command-ThatProducesJsonString | ConvertFrom-Json | Your-Function
```

If you want your powershell object to be converted back to json you can use `ConvertTo-Json` on the object. These utilities can make it wildly easier to handle the data since powershell handles data as objects which is different than traditional shells (bash) that handle data as streams of bytes.

Comment: The question is about how to pass a JSON string to the PowerShell CLI from outside PowerShell in a manner that makes PowerShell see it as a valid JSON string. It isn't about parsing an - of necessity valid - JSON string into an object model later.